# C: Condição de Parada Laço For

Tags: c, loop, for, char

Olá, alguém poderia me explicar por gentileza o que está acontecendo nessa condição de parada do laço for?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) { 

    char frase[] = "Linguagem C";
    
    for(int i = 0; frase[i]; i++) { //frase[i]?
        printf("%c", frase[i]);
    } 
    
    return 0;
}
```

A saída é: Linguagem C
Já utilizei o for várias outras vezes, mas nunca vi uma condição como essa.
Já no exemplo abaixo, é exibido além do conteúdo do vetor do tipo int:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) { 

    int vetor[] = {34, 42, -12, 984, 86, 14};
    
    for(int i = 0; vetor[i]; i++) { //A condição de parada é vetor[i]
        printf("%d\t", vetor[i]);
    }  
    
    return 0;
}
```

A saída é: 34      42      -12     984     86      14      1       7       136112
Acredito que os valores a partir do 14 são provavelmente "lixos na memória".
Mas por que isso acontece?

Comment: quer saber o porque dos lixos de memória?

Comment: Sim; acho que eles são valores armazenados na memória RAM por causa de outras aplicações, mas gostaria de ler a sua explicação por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Em C, não há por padrão o tipo lógico/boolean, C utiliza o número 0 para falso e qualquer outro valor diferente de 0 com sendo verdadeiro. No seu primeiro caso, o vetor de char, o '\0' que é o terminador de "string" em C é definido como 0, portanto quando i=11, vetor[11] será igual a 0 e o for termina. No seu segundo exemplo, o código é mais obscuro porque pode dar resultados diferentes, mas a ideia o for irá percorrer os dados em memória até encontrar um 0.

Comment: Consegui entender perfeitamente, muito obrigado!

Comment: Se a resposta te atendeu, aponte-a como resposta da questão.

Answer (score 0):

A sintaxe de um loop for tem a seguinte definição:

```
for( inicialização ; condição_de_saída ; incremento ) {}
```

O seu código é:

```
for( inicialização ; variável ; incremento ) {}
```

A definição de um loop for é flexível e permite até que as expressões sejam omitidas, mas colocar uma variável onde se espera uma expressão de condicional gera comportamento não definido. No seu caso a condicional foi definida implicitamente, mas mesmo para iterar em um char[] é errado pq basta um usuário entrar com uma sequência de caracteres que não termina em NULL para acontecer uma falha de segmentação pelo acesso de memória não autorizado.